# Node debug backtrace with file location?

Tags: node.js, debugging

When running the build-in node debug, I can use backtrace command line to show something like this

```
debug> backtrace
  #0 module.js:355:19
  #1 apikey.js:7:14
  #2 Module._compile module.js:411:26
  #3 Module._extensions module.js:417:10
  #4 Module.load module.js:343:31
  #5 Module._load module.js:302:12
  #6 Module.runMain module.js:430:10
  #7 startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback node.js:126:26
```

Is it possible to show the file location as well? e.g. If there are 5 index.js and they are appearing in the backtrace at the same time, how do I know which one I should look at?